# Complete list of albums and songs by 邓丽君。

Tags: lyrics

Where can I find a complete list of albums and songs by 邓丽君? I would like to access these for free or purchase all of them including the lyrics in simplified and traditional Chinese. I would like to store these on my phone and as mp3s and repeat-play any given song via an Android app. Thanks.

Comment: An incomplete list of official albums can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teresa_Teng#Studio_albums but there are thousands of bootlegs throughout East Asia. Huge compilations can be found in any store in China.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Chinese language.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of songs / album by 邓丽君 with link

http://music.baidu.com/artist/1091/song

However, you won't be able to listen to the songs if you visit this link outside of China. (You can still copy the song name in Chinese and search elsewhere)

Comment: Sadly, these songs will only play if you are accessing the page from China.

Comment: What if I'm not in China?

Comment: @JackMaddington They will not be played. Some websites are just like this. There are copyright issues. I don't really understand them. Although Hong Kong is part of China, you can't access some websites even if you are in Hong Kong!